# How to find a phrase in text file print out the result PHP?

Tags: php

I used this code to find the word in .txt file:

```
<?php
   $lines = file('testXml.txt');
   $what = array ( 'type="abbreviated">', 'type="international">');
    foreach ( $lines as $num => $line ) {
        foreach ( $what as $needle ) {
            $pos = strripos ( $line, $needle );
            if ( $pos !== false ) {
                echo "Line #<b>{$num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($line) . "<br />\n";
            }
        }
    } 
?>
```

and the output is:

```
Line #1 : <message id="nobill_54050898532262207218"> 
Line #4 : <destination messageid="54050898532262207218"> 
Line #6 : <number type="abbreviated">218</number> 
Line #11 : <number type="international">66830270995</number>
```

but i just want to get output like :

```
Line #6 : 218
Line #11 : 66830270995
```

How should I do ?

Complete text file:

```
<message id="nobill_54050898532262207218"> <sms type="mo"> <retry count="0" max="0"/> <destination messageid="54050898532262207218"> <address> <number type="abbreviated">218</number> </address> </destination> <source> <address> <number type="international">66830270995</number> </address> </source> <ud type="text">,TH</ud> <scts>2013-07-02T02:34:53Z</scts> <service-id></service-id> </sms> <from>nobill</from> <to>203.146.251.229:80</to> </message>
```

Thanks.

Comment: and this is my .txt file :

    info:
 <message id="nobill_54050898532262207218">
  <sms type="mo">
   <retry count="0" max="0"/>
   <destination messageid="54050898532262207218">
    <address>
     <number type="abbreviated">218</number>
    </address>
   </destination>
   <source>
    <address>
     <number type="international">66830270995</number>
    </address>
   </source>
   <ud type="text">,TH</ud>
   <scts>2013-07-02T02:34:53Z</scts>
   <service-id></service-id>
  </sms>
  <from>nobill</from>
  <to>203.146.251.229:80</to>
 </message>
sorry  i can't add info of .txt file above

Comment: Easiest way - use double split .... wanna more different solution? Use regex and create simple parser

Comment: yes, can differrent solution.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. I tested your code on the sample text file from your comment and it works fine - I get Line 6 and Line 11 only, as in your desired output. If you don't want the XML tags to be displayed, simply remove `htmlspecialchars()` and use `strip_tags` as @Webscrabbler suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strip_tags....

```
foreach ( $lines as $num => $line ) {
    foreach ( $what as $needle ) {
        $pos = strpos ( $line, $needle );
        if ( $pos !== false ) {
             echo "Line #<b>{$num}</b> : ". strip_tags($line);
        }
    }
 }
```

Or another hackish way...not recommended.

But notice the full tag in the $what array....

```
$what = array ( '<number type="abbreviated">', '<number type="international">');

foreach ( $lines as $num => $line ) {
    foreach ( $what as $needle ) {
        $pos = strpos ( $line, $needle );
        if ( $pos !== false ) {
            $t = explode("<",str_replace($needle,"",$line));
            echo "Line #<b>{$num}</b> : ". $t[0]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `htmlspecialchars($line)` with `strip_tags($line)`. This should remove all HTML opening and closing tags. Leaving out the content.

> Even though the content seems more XML like, the stip_tags function should work the same way.

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php